# Is there a way to get the location of the substring from which a certain token has been produced in BERT?

Tags: tokenize, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I am feeding sentences to a BERT model (Hugging Face library). These sentences get tokenized with a pretrained tokenizer. I know that you can use the decode function to go back from tokens to strings.

```
string = tokenizer.decode(...)
```

However, the reconstruction is not perfect. If you use an uncased pretrained model, the uppercase letters get lost. Also, if the tokenizer splits a word into 2 tokens, the second token will start with '##'. For example, the word 'coronavirus' gets split into 2 tokens: 'corona' and '##virus'.

So my question is: is there a way to get the indices of the substring from which every token is created?
For example, take the string "Tokyo to report nearly 370 new coronavirus cases, setting new single-day record". The 9th token is the token corresponding to 'virus'.

```
['[CLS]', 'tokyo', 'to', 'report', 'nearly', '370', 'new', 'corona', '##virus', 'cases', ',', 'setting', 'new', 'single', '-', 'day', 'record', '[SEP]']
```

I want something that tells me that the token '##virus' comes from the 'virus' substring in the original string, which is located between the indices 37 and 41 of the original string.

```
sentence = "Tokyo to report nearly 370 new coronavirus cases, setting new single-day record"
print(sentence[37:42]) # --> outputs 'virus
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know their is no built-in method for that, but you can create one by yourself:

```py
import re
from transformers import BertTokenizer

tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

sentence = "Tokyo to report nearly 370 new coronavirus cases, setting new single-day record"

b = []
b.append(([101],))
for m in re.finditer(r'\S+', sentence):
  w = m.group(0)
  t = (tokenizer.encode(w, add_special_tokens=False), (m.start(), m.end()-1))

  b.append(t)

b.append(([102],))

b
```

Output:

```
[([101],),
 ([5522], (0, 4)),
 ([2000], (6, 7)),
 ([3189], (9, 14)),
 ([3053], (16, 21)),
 ([16444], (23, 25)),
 ([2047], (27, 29)),
 ([21887, 23350], (31, 41)),
 ([3572, 1010], (43, 48)),
 ([4292], (50, 56)),
 ([2047], (58, 60)),
 ([2309, 1011, 2154], (62, 71)),
 ([2501], (73, 78)),
 ([102],)]
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to make an update to the answer. Since HuggingFace introduced their (much faster) version of Rust-written Fast Tokenizers, this task becomes much easier:

```
from transformers import BertTokenizerFast

tokenizer = BertTokenizerFast.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
sentence = "Tokyo to report nearly 370 new coronavirus cases, setting new single-day record"

encodings = tokenizer(sentence, return_offsets_mapping=True)
for token_id, pos in zip(encodings['input_ids'], encodings['offset_mapping']):
    print(token_id, pos, sentence[pos[0]:pos[1]])



101 (0, 0) 
5522 (0, 5) Tokyo
2000 (6, 8) to
3189 (9, 15) report
3053 (16, 22) nearly
16444 (23, 26) 370
2047 (27, 30) new
21887 (31, 37) corona
23350 (37, 42) virus
3572 (43, 48) cases
1010 (48, 49) ,
4292 (50, 57) setting
2047 (58, 61) new
2309 (62, 68) single
1011 (68, 69) -
2154 (69, 72) day
2501 (73, 79) record
102 (0, 0)
```

More than that, if instead of the regular string you feed the tokenizer with the list of words (and set `is_split_into_words=True`) then one can easily differentiate between first and the consequence tokens of each word (first value of the tuple would be zero), which is very common need for token classification tasks.